# Kotlin's scopes - exposing single entry point

Tags: kotlin

Hello I have a simple question about kotln's scopes. I always design my modules to get an single entry point for module. It's just one (exact one) `public` class. I really care for this kind of hermetization. So imagine these 2 classes (please pay attention for packages):

```
package group.moduleA.service
internal class HiddenService() {

    fun someFunction {

    }
}

  package group.moduleA.service
    class Service(private val hiddenService: HiddenService) {

        fun someFunction {

        }
    }
```

So we have 2 classes in same package, one is `public` and the second one `internal`. You can imagine there is a lot of `internal` classes there. I would like to make visible just only `Service` class to another modules. Pretty common (for me) behavior in Java. In kotlin I get an error:
"public function exposes its internal parameter..."
Am I doing something wrong or it's just how Kotlin scopes works? How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to declare the constructor `internal` or `private` and provide another 
function / constructor to create your service:

```
class Service internal constructor(private val hiddenService: HiddenService) {
    constructor() : this(HiddenService())

    fun someFunction() {

    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm can I use Spring's DI for this purpose?

Comment: class Service internal constructor(private val hiddenService: HiddenService) I think injection should work in this case. I will check it when get back to home, thanks :)

Comment: Oh great! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

[Dependency inversion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) is a good place to start:

```
internal class HiddenServiceImpl : HiddenService {
    override fun someFunction() {    
    }
}

interface HiddenService {
    fun someFunction()
}


class Service(private val hiddenService: HiddenService) {
    fun someFunction() {  
    }
}
```

Other option is to use factory method:

```
class Service private constructor(hiddenService: HiddenService) {

    companion object {
        fun create() = Service(HiddenService())
    }

    fun someFunction() {

    }
}
```

Comment: HiddenService interface is still visible outside module right?

Comment: If you want for someone to supply you the service, you'll have to make it public, as someone will be outside of your module. Spring DI is based on interfaces. Otherwise, use factory method pattern.

Comment: I want inject with Spring's DI internal class into public one. Requirement is to inject by constructor